# Discontinuities of Piecewise functions with undefined points

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, continuity, piecewise-continuity

In multiple class examples, and internet examples on discontinuities.
I often see that the undefined points are often called "the points at which the function is discontinuous". So If I have say a piecewise function:

$$ f(x) = 1 ; (x > 1) $$

and
$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{x} ; x\in[-1, 1] $$

I find examples that would say the function $1/x$ is undefined at x =0, thus it is discontinuous at said point.

Would we say those examples are incorrect, since the function 1/x is not defined at x = 0 ? Even if it is stated in the piecewise description that the interval we are considering does include x=0? Would we say the piecewise function is discontinuous at x =0?

I am just trying to clarify these concepts because many places share the wrong idea that "if a function f is not defined at a point, then it is said that the function is discontinuous at the said point"

Comment: If unsure, check the definition $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=f(a)$ for continuity at $a$. Even if you add the definition of $f(0)=0$, you get a discontinuity at $x=0$, since $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)\neq 0=f(0)$ (this limit is actually undefined).

Comment: So we then say the function is discontinuous at that point, even if the point is not on the domain?

Comment: No. Continuity (or the lack thereof) only makes sense at a point where the function is defined.

Comment: (btw, what you wrote is wrong in that you seem to give a value to f(x) when x is zero but what you wrote on the right of the equal sign does not make any sense in that case. Never write things that do not make sense.

Comment: Isn't your question more simply just "is `1/x is discontinuous at 0` true or false or not meaningful?" ? Or is there a point to mentioning piecewise functions?

Answer (score 1):

Discontinuity of some given function $f:D\to \mathbb{R}$ has nothing to do with being defined/undefined. For example, function $f(x) = \mathrm{sign}\;x = \begin{cases}1,\;x\geq 0\\-1,\;x<0\end{cases}$ is defined at every point $x\in\mathbb{R}$ from its domain, however it has discontinuity at $x=0$. At other points that are not from function's domain $D$ continuity makes no sense.

You can think of continuity in the following way: suppose you have a function $f$ and you want to check if it is continuous at $x\in D$. Then take a look at all points that are, say, to the left of $x$. Start approaching $x$ with these points. What value (of $f$) do you expect to get "by inertia"? Let's take a look at $\mathrm{sign}\;x$. If we take a sequence $x_{n} = -1/n$ that approaches $0$ from the left, we would expect our function to be $-1$ at $0$, because at every point $x_{n}$ we get $\mathrm{sign}\;x_{n} = -1$. But if one approaches $0$ from the right, he would expect function to be equal to $1$.
Note that even if both "observers" got the same value, it wouldn't guarantee the continuity of $f$ at $0$. In fact, you should run through all possible sequences, that converge to $0$ (and not equal $0$ at any term). However, this approach doesn't seem to work when $D$ is some "strange" set, or even not a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. To deal with such cases, I would recommend taking topology course.

Comment: thank you kindly for the answer, it becomes confusing as Algebra and Calculus 1 when they ask us to find the discontinuities for a function say 1/x, the answer is expected to say that the function is discontinuous at x= 0, so its domain are all points except the 0.